# Using Express proxy, how to change the relative url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-http-proxy

In order to avoid the typical CORS problem with client-side javascript code I use a nodejs express server. This server contains the following code:

```
var app = express();

  app.all('/Api/*', function (req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: 'https://www.myserver.com',
        changeOrigin:true
    });
  });
```

So what this does is redirect any call that starts with `/Api` to my server.

However, this also appends `Api` to the url path, so `Api/getData` becomes `https://www.myserver.com/Api/getData`

Is there way to strip the `Api` part of the relative url? The end result would be `Api/getData` becoming `https://www.myserver.com/getData`

This would allow me to target several servers by changing the first part of the relative url path. Something like this:

`Api/getData` -> `https://www.myserver.com/getData`

`OtherApi/getData/for/some/path` -> `https://www.some-other-server.com/getData/for/some/path`

This should of course work for all request types, not only for `GET`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [http-proxy-rules](https://github.com/donasaur/http-proxy-rules) module, which is a companion module for node-http-proxy. It allows you to write rules for changing matching routes to different proxy routes.

With it you should be able to define your translations like this:

```
var proxyRules = new HttpProxyRules({
    rules: {
      '.*/Api': 'http://myserver.com/', // Rule (1)
      '.*/OtherApi*': 'http://some-other-server.com:8080/' // Rule (2)
    },
    default: 'http://myserver.com/' // default target
  });
```

Then use them like this:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res) {
  var target = proxyRules.match(req);
  if (target) {
    return proxy.web(req, res, {
      target: target
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: Interesting! There is just soo much middleware out there it's hard to know what exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to modify `req.url` option. Something like:

```
app.all('/Api/*', function (req, res) {        
    req.url = req.url.split('/Api/')[1];
    proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
        changeOrigin:true
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmmm ... Can't be this simple ... Well you proved me wrong! thanks :)